# How to insert into a table field with value from a display method dependent of string

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

as you might know, this is a nice way to dynamically set values to fields.

```
myTable.(fieldName2Id(myTable.TableId, fieldNameStr)) = "This value";
myTable.insert();
```

What I am wondering about is if there is any way to do it in a similar fashion with display methods, just dynamically get the values from them?

If i have the Display method name (i.e. itemName()) how can I do this...?
something like this to demonstrate how i think:

```
methodNameStr = "ItemName";  
myTable.myField = mytable.(methodName2Id(myTable.TableId, methodNameStr));
myTable.insert();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DictTable.callObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dicttable.callobject(AX.60).aspx)(*medhodName*, buffer).

```cs
Common myTable;
DictTable dt;

//<SampleOnly>
str methodNameStr = "itemDescriptionOrName";
InventTable tmpTab;

select firstOnly tmpTab;
myTable = tmpTab;
//</SampleOnly>

dt = new DictTable(myTable.TableId);
dt.callObject(methodNameStr, myTable);

info(strFmt("%1", dt.callObject(methodNameStr, myTable)));
```